# Firestore: Why get runs in playground but not in app (as a query)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, rules

Data model: We have a collection `users`. Every user has a subcollection `posts` and every post has a subcollection `comments`. The key is that every post has a field `viewers` which is an array of user ids that CAN view the post. So the path of a comment is :

> users/{userid}/posts/{postid}/comments/{commentid}

The rules are :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read : if request.auth != null
    }
    
    match /users/{userId}/posts/{postId} {
        allow read, write: if  request.auth != null && ((request.auth.uid == userId) || (request.auth.uid in resource.data.viewers))
      allow update: if  request.auth != null && ((request.auth.uid == userId) || (request.auth.uid in resource.data.viewers))
    }
    
     match /users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId} {
        allow create,write : if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in get(/users/userId/posts/postId).data.viewers
        allow read: if request.auth != null && (request.auth.uid == userId || request.auth.uid==resource.data.uid)
    }
    
  }
}
```

In rules (playground) when i check to get a specific path like /users/userId1/posts/postId and in this post doc the array viewers has the id userId2, works fine (true). But in app the userId2 cant view others posts with error :

> failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Query in app :

```
db.collectionGroup("posts")
    .whereArrayContains("viewers",user.getUid())
    .whereEqualTo("visible", "visible").get()
```

Any ideas why that might happen?